# Нужно ли использовать прототипы функций в C++ в 2021

Tags: c++, c, ооп, прототипное-наследование

Учу С++, уровень - только начал проходить ООП по книжке 2013 года, и задаюсь вопросом, используют ли прототипы функций сегодня? Не устарела ли эта вещь? Смотрел видеоуроки, там прототипы не использовались, потому возник такой вопрос. Допустим, есть простой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Dict {
public:
    void help(char choice);
    void menu();
    bool isvalid(char ch);
};
void Dict::menu() {
        cout << "Выберите тему: (q для завершения)\n";
        cout << "1. if-else\n";
        cout << "2. while\n";
        cout << "3. for\n";
}
void Dict::help(char choice) {
    switch (choice)
    {
    case '1':
        cout << "if (проверка)\n";
        cout << "{код}\n"; break;
    case '2':
        cout << "while(выражение)\n";
        cout << "{код}\n"; break;
    case '3':
        cout << "for(int i=0; i<10;i++)\n";
        cout << "{код}\n"; break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
bool Dict::isvalid(char ch) {
    if (ch<'1'||ch>'3' && ch != 'q') { return false; }
    else {return true;}
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    Dict start;
    char choice;
    for (; ; )
    {
        do
        {
            start.menu();
            cin >> choice;
        } while (!start.isvalid(choice));
        if (choice == 'q') break;
        start.help(choice);
    }

}
```

Не проще ли сразу обьявить и написать функцию в теле класса? Заранее прощу прощения за возможную глупость вопроса, не нашел ответа)

Comment: Ну, например, функцию из 100 строк :) Или функцию, использующую класс, который будет объявлен после данного класса? А в видео прототипы не используются, потому что функции там учебные, на две строки в основном, вот в дидактических целях и не отделяют объявления от определения...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На самом деле прототипы функций никуда не делись, и их по-прежнему удобно использовать в тех случаях, когда в объявлениях класса лежит много методов. Если, например, Вы объявите и сразу же определите три-четыре метода внутри класса, то читаться это будет хуже, нежели поместить в класс объявления, а затем прописать их определения.

Вообще самым идеальным вариантом, на мой взгляд, является следующий:

1. Прописать класс и его объявления в некотором файле `sample.h`;
2. Прописать все определения ко всем методам (а также конструкторам, деструкторам, если необходимо) в другом файле `sample.cpp`. Этот файл и `sample.h` называются [заголовочными файлами](https://ravesli.com/urok-21-zagolovochnye-fajly/), и они могут значительно улучшить разделяемость и читаемость кода.

TL;DR, если для Вас важна читаемость кода, то я бы порекомендовал способ выше. Если же нужно написать что-то достаточно простое, то можно и прописать прямо внутри класса (но тогда будут проблемы с читабельностью кода).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, теперь стало понятнее.

Comment: *"объявите и сразу же определите три-четыре метода внутри класса, то читаться это будет хуже"* - ¿почему? Общий объем кода сократится, не придется прыгать между объявлением и реализацией.

Comment: *"sample.cpp. Этот файл и sample.h называются заголовочными файлами"* - Заголовочный тут - только `.h`, не `.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

Традиционно в С, а затем и в С++ был в ходу подход с раздельной компиляцией, когда объявления помещались в заголовочный файл, а определения в файл реализации. Это позволяло при изменении реализации пересобирать только одну единицу трансляции (инкрементальная сборка). Однако при длительном использовании такой подход очень плохо масштабируется, приводя к неадекватному времени сборки проектов. Сейчас имеет смысл перестать просто так разделять объявление и реализацию и переключаться на [подход с SCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit).

Далее, в разделении на определение и реализацию может быть и объективная необходимость. Она возникает как следствие взаимной зависимости, в ситуации, когда идентификатор должен объявлен перед использованием, но не может быть при этом сразу определен:

```
class foo1
{
    public: void bar1();
};

class foo2
{
    public: foo1 & m_foo1;

    public: void bar2()
    {
        m_foo1.bar1();
    }
};

inline void foo1::bar1()
{
    foo2 f2{*this};
    f2.bar2();
}
```

Comment: В примере из вопроса никакого смысла в разделении на объявление и реализацию нет.

Comment: Я понимаю ибо еще совсем неопытный, и писать хоть немного сложные проекты не умею